# How to interpret stagnant validation curve

Tags: deep-learning, classification, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network, auc

I'm new to deep learning, so I'm just learning how to interpret my models.

I'm creating a mixed-convolutional neural net to classify [melanoma images](https://www.kaggle.com/c/siim-isic-melanoma-classification).

Here's the model structure:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 80, 120, 3)] 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 80, 120, 32)  896         input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 40, 60, 32)   0           conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 40, 60, 64)   18496       max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 20, 30, 64)   0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 20, 30, 32)   18464       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 10, 15, 32)   0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 2065)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 4800)         0           max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 64)           132224      input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 1024)         4916224     flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            65          dense[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            1025        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
average (Average)               (None, 1)            0           dense_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_3[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 5,087,394
Trainable params: 5,087,394
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I then compile and fit:

```
model.compile('adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[auc])

epochs = 15
history = model.fit([meta_train, img_train], y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=300, validation_data=([meta_test, img_test], y_test))
```

When I run the model, I get an increase in AUC for the training data, but the validation AUC is stagnant--it starts higher than the training AUC, but never moves:

[image: AUC]

Is it correct to attribute this to overfitting? Wouldn't the validation AUC go *lower* if it was overfitting, rather than remaining relatively stagnant? How do I interpret this?

---

**EDIT**

Metadata includes age bins and dummied categorical variables of patient ID, sex, and location on body (torso, upper/lower extremity, etc.)

Comment: I woudn't attribute such behaviour to overfitting, it seems something is definitly off with your modeling, can you add which informations are in the 'meta' part of the data, I feel the problem comes from this part, would you mind telling us what exactly is being fed to the network in the metadatas. 2 things you can try tho : replace the average with a concatenate + dense layer; remove the input1 part and see how the CNN behaves.

Comment: Could you should the loss curves apart from the AUC ones?